# Does gatherable objects health multiplier change the amount of resources you receive from a resource node?

Tags: palworld

In the custom settings, there are several settings related to gatherable objects. The Gatherable Items Multiplier seems to increase the amount of resources you acquire while farming resource nodes or collecting items laying on the ground. The Gatherable Objects Health Multiplier is a little less clear though.
[image]

Does lowering this setting just make it faster to farm the node, or does it also decrease the amount of resources I would get?

Answer (score 1):

## Yes

Based on experimentation, the amount of item you get is based on the amount of damage you deal to the object. So, if the object has half as much health, it will drop half as many items.

To normalize this, you need to turn up the **Gatherable Items Multiplier** to increase the amount of items you get per chunk of health removed so as to make it that you get the same amount of item per node.

| Gatherable Items Multiplier | Gatherable Objects Health Multiplier | Wood per Tree | Time to punch tree |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.0 | 1.0 | 24 | 10s |
| 1.0 | 0.5 | 12 | 5s |
| 0.5 | 1.0 | 12 | 10s |
| 0.5 | 0.5 | 6 | 5s |
| 2.0 | 0.5 | 24 | 5s |
| 1.0 | 1000 | 2400 | 2h 46m 40s (10000s) |
| 1000 | 1.0 | 2400 | 10s |

The "time to punch tree" is calculated on the the assumption you have unlimited stamina, and are using a Stone Axe (first tier).

Note that changing the setting does not retrospectively change health multipliers; they need to respawn for it to take effect.

Comment: I think each tree has the same wood, too, which is really odd considering the variety of different shapes and sizes.